# update state object with mutliple fields without overwritting

Tags: reactjs, state

I am using a state that at the start contains nothing. I want to update it with multiple input values. But when I try to do so my input value are just overwritting each other.
For instance, let's say I set my input to test first then my object will be value : msg1 : 'test' but if I go in the second input and I type "test2" my object value will then be msg2 : 'test2' not the both together and that's what I want.

```
{
{name1:name1, value1: value1},
{name2:name2,  value2:value2} 
} 
/* OR something like this */
{
value1: value1,
value2: value2
}
```

I want it to be value1:'test' value2:'test2

```
const [msgCount, setMsgCount] = useState({});
const handleChange = name => value => {
        setTicketCount({name,value});
    }
<input type='number' onChange={handleChange('msg'+1)} />
<input type='number' onChange={handleChange('msg'+2)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The setter of `useState` does not merge state like `this.setState` in class component, therefore you should use the functional update API:

```
// name === 'msg1', value = user text
const handleChange = name => value => {
  setTicketCount(prevState => ({...prevState, [name]: value});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to map an array to create a component for each input and put the states inside the component so it will duplicate the states along with the inputs https://stackoverflow.com/a/71973070/14548500

Comment: Hi, I have a map for my inputs.